# Stack Overflow requires cookies for authentication—and YES, my browser cookies are enabled for this domain

Tags: bug, login, cookies, github

This problem seems to have been around for about a decade, but it's Feb 2023 and it still lives. I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome running Windows 11.

I tried to create a new Stack Overflow account using the 'Sign Up With GitHub' option at "stackoverflow.com/users/signup." After filling in all the information I got the message, "Stack Overflow requires cookies for authentication -- are your browser cookies enabled for this domain?"

I cleared all cookies for Stack Exchange per previous posts on the subject, went into Chrome settings and allowed all cookies for Stack Overflow, but the problem kept occurring. I was able to create an account the old-fashioned way without using GitHub.

Comment: I guess you also have to enable cookies for github if you use github authentication?

Comment: My cookie settings are whatever the Chrome defaults are, I normally don't have to do anything with them when signing up for/into a site.